# when we run our application then it shows unfortunetly,application has stopped

Tags: android

```
04-08 00:46:02.390: D/AndroidRuntime(918): Shutting down VM
04-08 00:46:02.390: W/dalvikvm(918): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4acab90)
04-08 00:46:02.420: E/AndroidRuntime(918): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 00:46:02.420: E/AndroidRuntime(918): Process: net.gnobal.dindy, PID: 918
04-08 00:46:02.420: E/AndroidRuntime(918): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application net.gnobal.dindy.DindyApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "net.gnobal.dindy.DindyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/net.gnobal.dindy-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/net.gnobal.dindy-1, /system/lib]]
04-08 00:46:02.420: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
04-08 00:46:02.420: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4298)
04-08 00:46:02.420: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-08 00:46:02.420: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1457)
04-08 00:46:02.420: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-08 00:46:02.420: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-08 00:46:02.420: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
04-08 00:46:02.420: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 00:46:02.420: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-08 00:46:02.420: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
04-08 00:46:02.420: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
04-08 00:46:02.420: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 00:46:02.420: E/AndroidRuntime(918): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "net.gnobal.dindy.DindyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/net.gnobal.dindy-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/net.gnobal.dindy-1, /system/lib]]
04-08 00:46:02.420: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
04-08 00:46:02.420: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
04-08 00:46:02.420: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
04-08 00:46:02.420: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
04-08 00:46:02.420: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
04-08 00:46:02.420: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  ... 11 more
04-08 00:46:07.430: I/Process(918): Sending signal. PID: 918 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have a file named DindyApplication in package net.gnobal.dindy??

Comment: and make sure that you've specified the class in manifest correctly. if possible, post your manifest too..

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22959847/3168859)..see if it helps..

Comment: app is still not working the link of our source code is    https://github.com/gnobal/Dindy.git

Answer (score 0):

Check your package name and also check whether the class name i.e activity is properly registered in the manifest.

Comment: app is still not working and the link of source code is  https://github.com/gnobal/Dindy.git