# Refactoring package name breaks app with ClassNotFoundException due to not finding the Application class even though it is there

Tags: android, android-studio, refactoring, package, classnotfoundexception

I **had** this package format:

```
com
  example
    name
      oldAppName
```

**Now**, I refactored and renamed by Shift+F6 to **this:**

```
com
  myCompanyName
    name
      newAppName
```

However,now when I run my app, I get this crash:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.name.oldAppName.Application" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myCompanyName.name.newAppName1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I have my `Application.java` under `newAppName`, and it is defined in the Manifest correctly
**What I tried and did were:**

- *Cleaning and Rebuilding*
- Changing `applicationId` in build.gradle
- The package name in manifest is correct and so are all the names of the App and Activities.

In fact, here's my application manifest tag:

```
<application
  android:name=".Application"
  ...
  >
```

**Even changing `.Application` to the full package name (`com.blah.blah.Application`)** *DIDN'T WORK.*

Am I missing something? Is there a missing step?

**Here's the full log:**

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.name.oldAppName.Application
      at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4345)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.name.oldAppName.Application
      at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.createRealApplication(BootstrapApplication.java:220)
      at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.attachBaseContext(BootstrapApplication.java:239)
      at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:181)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1008)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:992)
      at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4345) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.name.oldAppName.Application
      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
      at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.createRealApplication(BootstrapApplication.java:209)
      at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.attachBaseContext(BootstrapApplication.java:239) 
      at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:181) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1008) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:992) 
      at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4345) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.name.oldAppName/Application
      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251) 
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216) 
      at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.createRealApplication(BootstrapApplication.java:209) 
      at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.attachBaseContext(BootstrapApplication.java:239) 
      at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:181) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1008) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:992) 
      at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4345) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.name.oldAppName.Application" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.newCompanyName.name.newAppName-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.myCompanyName.name.newAppName-1, /system/lib]]
      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251) 
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216) 
      at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.createRealApplication(BootstrapApplication.java:209) 
      at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.attachBaseContext(BootstrapApplication.java:239) 
      at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:181) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1008) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:992) 
      at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4345) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866431/android-activity-classnotfoundexception-tried-everything?rq=1   or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399572/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path-dexpathlist

Comment: @Stefan those are both using Eclipse and are outdated.

Comment: Those still have some interesting answers below. Have you checked your imported libraries versions? Clean app cache and uninstall it completely then try to build again?

Comment: @Stefan nothing you mentioned worked

Comment: In application tag android:name is not mandatory so did u tried to remove the same and rebuild your application.

Comment: @abbaspiplodawala but I need the Application class as I am setting some things in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes, **disabling Instant Run** will solve the issue.

**Or, if disabling Instant Run didn't work**, the problem could be with Android Studio not recognizing the changes yet. **BACKUP YOUR PROJECT FIRST** and note that you'll have to re-configure your VCS after this (but no commits or branches will be lost, just the registration of your VCS.)

Delete the .idea and [yourProjectName].iml of your app.

---

## For future users:

---

#### The right way to rename packages in Android Studio

1. In your Project pane, choose the gear icon
2. Uncheck "**Compact Empty Middle Packages**" if checked.

[image: Gear icon example]

3. Now go on with **refactor->rename** for every broken down package name (essentially com, example, name, oldAppName)
4. Rename might open a waring dialog in which you might have to choose **Rename Package**

[image: Warning dialog example]

5. Once renaming package is done, Replace `applicationId` in gradle with the correct one
6. Sync gradle
7. clean and rebuild

You could find a better version of how to properly refactor your package [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)

*P.S: you must revert to the original package name at the point where you did not get "ClassNotFound" exception and try the above solution.*

Comment: Probably a wild suggestion. Could you disable instant run, remove app and re-run the project? Instant run has failed in few instances for me

Comment: did you run a find usage check on your old package name? and double check your package name for typos in both manifest and build.gradle

Comment: Also check your Application class hierarchy. Probably its in `com.mycompanyname.name` rather than in `com.mycompanyname.name.newAppName` or somewhere else. Also, assuming the class name in the actual question is exactly same as you have in code, you cannot have `Application` as class name

Comment: I did a Find-Replace after the refactoring and replaced the old package with the new one. Still nothing

Comment: Wait. I renamed my `Application` class to `MyActualAppName`. Now it crashes, **but with the SAME error**. Nothing changes, it still says `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.name.oldAppName.Application` instead of `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.name.oldAppName.MyActualAppName`. This is weird.

Comment: And as a plus, when I remove `android:name` from my `<application>` tag, the error still occurs.

Comment: That makes me believe that android studio didnt pick up package changes correctly. Can you close the project, delete `.idea`folder and the .iml file in project root and reimport project in android studio?
Warning: Make a backup before and any vcs config will be lost and has to be configured again

Comment: That makes sense. I'll check it out

Comment: Ok, did that. Now, thanks to Android's marvelous logic, it's forcing me to update everything. :)\

Comment: I can award my bounty in 6 hours. It will be awarded to you. :)

Comment: That's fine @AbAppletic :)

Comment: The Android Gradle plugin is aggressively caching an artifact used by instant run to retrieve your application id and application class. You can workaround the problem by doing `rm -rf ~/.android/build-cache` (there is a way to limit deletion by doing `find ~/.android/build-cache -type f | xargs grep -l AppInfo` and deleting only matching cache folders) and then doing a clean rebuild then launch of your app. This will fix the issue until the next application Id/package rename. See details here
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=229128#c8

Answer (score 3):

For those coming here, in at least Android Gradle plugin version 2.2.3, there is a bug aggressively caching an artifact used by instant run to retrieve your application id and application class. You can workaround the problem by doing `rm -rf ~/.android/build-cache` and then doing a clean rebuild then launch your app.

There is a way to limit deletion by doing `find ~/.android/build-cache -type f | xargs grep -l AppInfo` and deleting only matching cache folders:

```
$ find ~/.android/build-cache -type f | xargs grep -l AppInfo
/Users/joe/.android/build-cache/dde3e201178401491cae141d479a0b4113bf3a0e/output/classes.dex
/Users/joe/.android/build-cache/f7d636c8af71d68edfb468297d20157f3eb6659c/output/classes.dex

$ rm -rf /Users/joe/.android/build-cache/dde3e201178401491cae141d479a0b4113bf3a0e
$ rm -rf /Users/joe/.android/build-cache/f7d636c8af71d68edfb468297d20157f3eb6659c
```

This will fix the issue until the next application id/package rename.

See details here [code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=229128#c8](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=229128#c8)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar problem after refactoring one of my java class, and I resolved it by cleaning the project structure.

1. Go to Build
2. Click on the clean project option

After this, everything got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing a clean build, do check the following below to ensure the following all have been updated with the new class name.

1. class name on Directory: MainActivity
2. class: public class MainActivity extends ....
3. Manifest:
4. XML: tools:context=".MainActivity"

After which, you do a clean build/rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

#### Refactoring the name of a Qt based Android app

For those coming here after seeing the exact same error messages when trying to rename a Qt based Android application: to rename it simply adapt the following XML attributes in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<!-- application package name as seen in Google Play URLs, 
     in the output of `adb shell pm list packages` etc. -->
<manifest package="com.example.appname" …>

<!-- application name as shown below the app icon -->
<application … android:label="App Name" …>

<!-- application name "sometimes" shown below the app icon -->
<activity … android:label="appname" …>
```

Do not touch the following attributes, because that would lead to the symptoms described here:

```
<application … android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtApplication" …>

<activity … android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity" …>
```

The reason is that in a Qt application for Android, you do not define the Android activity to launch in your `main.cpp` or something. Instead, the program `anroiddeployqt` generates bootstrap Java code that eventually calls your C++ code from `main.cpp`. That bootstrap code needs the application and activity names as seen above. But you can change their labels (display names) – see above.