# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass

Tags: java, android

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.me.hexavoidaa/com.me.hexavoidaa.PTPlayer}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.me.hexavoidaa.PTPlayer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.me.hexavoidaa-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.me.hexavoidaa-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2208)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.me.hexavoidaa.PTPlayer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.me.hexavoidaa-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.me.hexavoidaa-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Maybe problem with multidex implementation, refer [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: Have you added the activity to the manifest?

Comment: I suggest you look here for some possible solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399572/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path-dexpathlist

Comment: did you add PTPlayer class in manifest ?

Comment: same problem here. Have no idea... guys explain why downvotes?

Comment: I have the exact same issue and my apk does not require multidex (APK analyzer shows that the referenced methods are below 64K). Any ideas?

Comment: Seeing this issue surface in logs, unable to reproduce. Have Multidex implemented properly.

Answer (score 4):

add this to gradle.build:

```
defaultConfig {
...
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion // your version 
...

// Enabling multidex support.
multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

- follow  android developers page's instruction: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: I have a very small app and yet still have this issue: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager . Do you think I should enable multiDex? I noticed it occurs (for now) only on Android 5.1 and below, yet the docs say that it shouldn't occur on Android 5.0 and above...

Comment: @androiddeveloper I'm having the exact same issue with devices running Android 5.1 and below. Did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: Same issue! With 5.0, 5.1 and 5.1.1!

Answer (score 3):

In Android 9 likely to help adding to manifest into "application" tag:

```
<uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />
```

Comment: How is this supposed to help with ClassNotFound?

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, this could be a MultiDex issue. Try this in your application class. That is in `App.java` which extends `Application`:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this); // this is the key code
}
```

source: https://github.com/opendatakit/collect/issues/387

Comment: still issue occurs

Comment: this only needed if your App class already extends some other class and you can't extend from MultiDexApplication

Answer (score 1):

if you already added multidex in both gradle and manifest then try to disable instant run and then create apk to test, i was facing same issue and searched a lot and tried every solution but at last this solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

**Solved:**

***Step 1:*** create MyApp class as follows:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this); // this is the key code
    }
}
```

***Step 2:***
Add the name property to the app in the manifest as follows:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication">
```