# Google Play- java.lang.ClassNotFoundException - Phonegap Build Error (App closes when open first time)

Tags: phonegap

**Phonegap Build Error**

Hi,

When I compile my application through build.phonegap.com and downloaded the APK directly on phone, the app was working fine. But the same APK when I uploaded to Google Play and when I installed that app it CRASH for the first time when I open it. When I check the error in Google Crash Report, I found this "**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass**".

And the whole error was

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaqc.zzbm (Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver.onReceive (Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3099)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18 (ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1610)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:163)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6239)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:904)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:794)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:380)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
```

Please, can anyone tell me the solution for that?

Comment: You should provide some more information like what CLI are u using, what is your target SDK version and which Android version are u running on the phone? Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41426853/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-in-dalvik-system-basedexclassloader-findclass

Comment: <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.0.1" />  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="17" />    
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="26" />