# How to fix "dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)"

Tags: android, google-play, android-9.0-pie, dexclassloader

After I upgraded to the 64-bit armeabi library and released the app to googleplay in bundle packaging, I encountered the following problems in googleplay crashes report page:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3982)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300 (ActivityThread.java:273)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2050)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:112)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:216)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7625)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:524)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:987)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver (AppComponentFactory.java:84)
  at android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver (CoreComponentFactory.java:56)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3975)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300 (ActivityThread.java:273)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2050)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:112)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:216)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7625)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:524)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

It's only appear on the Android 9 devices

I turn off the R8 in my leatest release version app.But it's appear just like before.Problem still happen

wish your help

Comment: So any solution?

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution for this!

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution too!

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53982361/android-error-dalvik-system-basedexclassloader-findclass

Answer (score 4):

add this to gradle.build:

```
defaultConfig {
...
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion // your version 
...

// Enabling multidex support.
multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

- follow  android developers page's instruction: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: Why would multidex help with this issue?

Comment: @user2811667 did you manage to solve it by this answer ? or anyone ?

Comment: I don't think this is a solution since my project has it already enabled. I wasn't able to reproduce the issue though, just 1 crash reported by Crashlytics.

Answer (score -3):

just add the below line of code within the "application" element of AndroidManifest.xml.

`

```
    <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />

         ...........
         ..........
</application>
```

`

Comment: I need a solution for this too