# First time open crash android game build by unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, runtime-error

Hello everyone i publish a wordcard game on playstore. I build it from unity. Whenever someone downloads my app and opens it crashing with this error.

After second attempt its not crashing. How can find what is cause this.

Add comment

```
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
 Unity version     : 2019.1.4f1
 Device model      : samsung GT-I9060I
 Device fingerprint: samsung/grandneove3gxx/grandneove3g:4.4.4/KTU84P/I9060IXXS0AQC2:user/release-keys
 Caused by
  1 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:2648)
  2 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700 (ActivityThread.java:166)
  3 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1359)
  4 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  5 at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
  6 at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5584)
  7 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  8 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  9 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1268)
  10 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1084)
  11 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
   1 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
   2 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:497)
   3 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:457)
   4 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:2643)
```

Comment: probably a MultiDex issue. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41426853/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-in-dalvik-system-basedexclassloader-findclass) question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41426853/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-in-dalvik-system-basedexclassloader-findclass)