# Published App crashes when installed from the playstore

Tags: ionic3

Deployed Ionic 3 app crashes after publishing to the playstore.

Hello,
 I have generated the Android App Bundle for my existing  Ionic 3 app. I could generate the apk locally and run it . but once I generate  the .aab and push it to the playstore the app crashes.

The crash report gives the foll error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass

On doing a bit of googling I found  this stackoverflow post :
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41426853/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-in-dalvik-system-basedexclassloader-findclass)

But did not work.

Can anyone please help me.