# Simple Helloworld app throw exception after run in real device

Tags: android, nativescript

i am install nativescript latest 2.5.0 and modules, 
create simple helloworld app, 
it work perfect in emulator API 19, 
but fails on real device with android 4.4.4:

> An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.HelloWorld/org.nativescript.HelloWorld.NativeScriptActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "org.nativescript.HelloWorld.NativeScriptActivity" on path:
>   DexPathList

i manual fix manifest by deleting name of activity to : `.NativeScriptActivity`
and error again: `metadata.getInt` is not a function...

i read all forums but my problem stil not solved..

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="__PACKAGE__"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">

            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you add org.nativescript.HelloWorld.NativeScriptActivity to manifest ?

Comment: try clean and build your project.

Comment: refer this.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399572/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path-dexpathlist

Comment: can you share you AndroidMenifest.xml file and activity

Comment: thanx for attention. i must have two strings about activity?

Comment: i add my manifest

Comment: adding multidex does nothing...

Comment: @ТимурМалышев you have not mentioned your package name above at manifest. Second thing your activity package name is com.tns.NativeScriptActivity and your log error shows some different package name. So you need provide all required and correct data.

Comment: after all changes in manifest i have this: js method onCreate failed activityInfo.metaData.getInt is not a function

Comment: @ТимурМалышев I will assume that your device runs some kind of MIUI on the device of API Level 19, is that correct? The problem comes from the fact that the MIUI android library distribution differs from the standard SDK. It is a known issue to the NativeScript team. https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime/issues/404