# Multidex installation failure

Tags: java, android, android-multidex

I'm using CircledImageView library. It works fine on lollipop+ android versions. But in kitkat it's crashing. So after searching on google. I found that i have to implement multidex in my app.

So this my application class.

```
public class FireApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        Fresco.initialize (this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

And in build.gradle under defaultconfig MultiDexEnabled is true

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

But when I run the app, I get the following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: Field dexElementsSuppressedExceptions not found in class dalvik.system.PathClassLoader
 at android.support.multidex.MultiDex.findField(MultiDex.java:288)
 at android.support.multidex.MultiDex.access$300(MultiDex.java:57)
 at android.support.multidex.MultiDex$V19.install(MultiDex.java:390)
 at android.support.multidex.MultiDex$V19.access$000(MultiDex.java:369)
 at android.support.multidex.MultiDex.installSecondaryDexes(MultiDex.java:242)
 at android.support.multidex.MultiDex.install(MultiDex.java:161)
 at android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication.attachBaseContext(MultiDexApplication.java:39)
 at com.buckydroid.anonchat.FireApp.attachBaseContext(Unknown Source)
 at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:182)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:991)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
 at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4564)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1353)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: First of all, no need to both extend the MultiDexApplication and call MultiDex.install(this). Choose one of them. On which device are you having this error?

Comment: I'm getting this error on my zenfone5 android kitkat @AlexLipov

Comment: Still i got no solution :(

Comment: I don't have such device, so I can't test. If you'll check the source, you'll see that the library tries to find the [dexElementsSuppressedExceptions](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/multidex/+/android-7.1.1_r23/library/src/android/support/multidex/MultiDex.java#428) field, which is a private field of [DexPathList](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/kitkat-mr2.2-release/dalvik/src/main/java/dalvik/system/DexPathList.java#70) class. Which (exact) Android version your Zenfone 5 device is running?

Comment: If it's API level 19, then Asus probably altered the internal implementation of DexPathList (at least this is what it seems from your exception). If this is the case - I'm curious how other multi-dex applications work on your device (i.e., does Uber run on your device?)..

Comment: No man, It's some problem in code. I tried in all pre lolipop devices on virtual testing offered by firebase and same error @AlexLipov

Comment: Can you share your gradle file?

Comment: please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43274600/3960700)

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41479407/6478047) solution once

Comment: I'd be interested in the logs with tag `"MultiDex"` and message `"Exception in makeDexElement"` just before your actual error.

Comment: Maybe related https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210188

Comment: Enable Dex in you default config file   "multiDexEnabled true"

Comment: I came across the same problem with my app and has solved it. For my case, this error appeared after I stopped an on-going gradle build process during my first build. To solve it, I cleaned the entire project and rebuild it again. Not sure why, but it solved the error, so maybe anyone who came across this same problem could try my solution

Answer (score 3):

Try including `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: This answer is misleading. The library already included, otherwise he wouldn't get this exception.

Comment: @AlexLipov OP included version 1.0.0. The newest is 1.0.1.

Answer (score 3):

check following steps this steps

1) Add dependency in your build.gradle file :

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

2) Enable multidex and set heap size

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your package name"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

3) In Application class add this

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

4) Add this in your manifest in `<application>` tag :

```
android:name=".YourApplicationClassName"
```

Comment: Points 1, 2 (multiDexEnabled), 3, 4 are already done. Point 2 (java heap size) affects *compilation* not *runtime*.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure the application declared in the manifest file extends `MultiDexApplication`.
2. Make sure your `build.gradle` file enabled multidexing and included the `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` package dependency.
3. Make sure your are not being trolled by Android Studio fast build. You can remove all build directories and install using the application using command line.
4. If your application has flavours, make sure the installed flavor is using `MultiDexApplication`

Comment: As mentioned by @alex-lipov, remove `MultiDex.install(this)` make  sure your application `FireApp` is inheriting from `MultiDexApplication`, not `Application` and also `android:name=".FireApp"`. Usually I repeat this check before start looking for other insane multidexing bugs ;-)

Comment: Having `MultiDex.install(this)` is functionally equivalent to extending `MultiDexApplication`.

Comment: The 3rd point of "remove all build directories". The comment by "JP Ventura" of removing MultiDex.install(this) with method in Application class worked for me. I had other things in proper place.

Answer (score 2):

Try this
Inside your app level build.gradle file put the following line of code

```
android{
      //compielsdkVersion..
      //..
      //..
      vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

and in the Activity.java that you are using the CircularImageView put the following static block on the top of onCreate() method like this

```
    //...
   //....
    static {
            AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //...
   //...
```

Comment: OP didn't get as far as actually starting an acitvity. Your answer is unrelated to the multidex issue.

Answer (score 1):

previous solutions are ok but one missing thing
**MultiDexApplication**

```
public class FireApp extends MultiDexApplication
```

Comment: Having `MultiDex.install(this)` is functionally equivalent to extending `MultiDexApplication`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your application tag in your manifest

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

Comment: But under application tag. I have added this android:name=".FireApp"

Comment: Can't you replace that line with line which I have given to you?

Comment: This answer is misleading. The OP already configured his application to extend MultiDexApplication. You just offer another way to do the same thing (or even worse, you're asking him to not use his FireApp application class which may have custom logic).

Answer (score 0):

On API 19 and 20, the library was trying to save "suppressed exceptions"
in the loader.dexElementsSuppressedExceptions.

But the field is not there, it's in DexPathList, so the correct path is
loader.pathList.dexElementsSuppressedExceptions.

Google has fixed it: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/multidex/+/74e66b8013b5b9002f67e53825c189a18597b1e8%5E%21/#F0

You need to update multidex version to 1.0.2+.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem on a Sony device running Android 4.3 (API 18) on **debug** build (release was ok). After trying every single solution out there and making sure to do everything right I was still not able to fix the issue.

As I was building and installing my APK using Android Studio for several devices I accidently found that if I try to **build it for a Lollipop device** once and then build it for an older version (below KitKat) it will run without the annoying `MultiDex installation failed` error.

Note that my own device which I use most often to build and test the app runs API 28.

Answer (score -2):

this is a error in kitkat multidex，u can override the V19.install, cause dexElementsSuppressedExceptions is the field in dexPathList, not in loader. However, there is exception when dalvik do makeDexElements, but you get the wrong message instead[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4tW8.png)

Answer (score -3):

try including 
`compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1`' in your build.gradle file.

Comment: This answer is equivalent to an answer posted 3 weeks ago.