# Getting "package android.support.multidex does not exist" after upgrading to Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools, android-multidex

I updated from Android  Studio 2.2.3 to Android Studio 2.3 yesterday, and I ran into the following two problems:

- Upon updating, Gradle 3.2 was installed by default, but syncing my
  project would not work and I kept getting an error saying "Gradle 3.3
  is required". Using the default Gradle wrapper doesn't work. The only way to fix this was to download Gradle 3.3
  manually and point to the directory in build settings.
- On running my project, I kept getting a string of errors involving my
  `BaseApplication` class which extends `MultiDexApplication`. The
  error goes something like this:

  > `Error:(19, 62) error: package android.support.multidex does not exist`

I am unable to resolve this error. I have `buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'`, and my project compiled and ran properly before upgrading to Android Studio 2.3. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41479407/6478047)  once,not sure if it will work, just check once

Comment: just go to settings>build, execution, deployment>gradle> and select "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)" then rebuild

Comment: @ScottS: I have already tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: in your build.gradle do you have multidex enabled and if so have you imported multidex library as part of the dependencies? com.android.support:multidex:x.x.x'  in your manifest do you have this line added? package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication" within manifest tag? post your gradle and your manifest if still need help

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'   try add that to dependencies in build.gradle

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to add the following:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

in your `build.gradle` file.

This was not required prior to Gradle 3.3. This problem occurs only for apps that support Android versions below Lollipop (API level 21).

**References:**

**1.** [**Multidex support prior to Android 5.0**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-pre-l).

Comment: `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'`
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-pre-l

Answer (score 68):

I have passed the building. my solution is that adding explicit dependencies  in build.gradle.
    `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`

Answer (score 10):

Replace
 `import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;` 
with 
`import androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication;`

Answer (score 3):

what works for me is adding to your (app) `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

It is necessary to add this:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```