# ClassNotFoundException (AppCompatActivity.class) after moving Android studio project from Windows to Mac

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio, android-support-library

:)

I'm currently working on an Android app using Android Studio and after I have worked on it quite a while on my Windows machine, I am currently trying to get it running on my MacBook Air.

I copied the project files and created an Emulator on the Mac (API 25). The project compiles just fine, but it immediately crashes on the Emulator due to the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.lennartschoch.partytime, PID: 5736
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.lennartschoch.partytime/com.lennartschoch.partytime.LoadingActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.lennartschoch.partytime.LoadingActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.lennartschoch.partytime-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lennartschoch.partytime-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.lennartschoch.partytime-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.lennartschoch.partytime.LoadingActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.lennartschoch.partytime-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lennartschoch.partytime-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.lennartschoch.partytime-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                                           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
                                                                        Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity;
                                                                           at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:742)
                                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
                                                                                ... 12 more
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.lennartschoch.partytime-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lennartschoch.partytime-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.lennartschoch.partytime-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                                           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                ... 15 more
```

I have (hopefully) currectly implemented the Android Support Library (v7) which you can see in my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lennartschoch.partytime"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner         "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
}
```

I've already tried cleaning and rebuilding the project but I just cannot get rid of the problem. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399572/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path-dexpathlist

Comment: You don't need v7. The design library includes it already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dependencies {   

 compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'

       }
```

Use these dependencies.

Comment: Keep the versions the same

Comment: @cricket_007 worked like a charme! Thanks a lot :) Do you know why version 25.3.1 seems to cause these issues only on Mac, but not on Windows?

Comment: @Lenn No idea.. I always have used the latest versions on my mac

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after moving an Android project to a subdirectory of the old directory. First, when I tried to run the project on the same device as earlier I got the following error:

```
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
Error while Installing APKs
```

I got rid of this by doing `Build -> Clean Project`, but then I was getting these `ClassNotFound` exceptions and the app was immediately crashing. This was solved by running `gradlew clean` in terminal in the project root directory and building again.