# ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.xxx.xxx.Application" on path: DexPathList on Linux

Tags: java, android, linux, macos

I've moved from Mac to a linux machine (ubuntu) and and can't get the previous project running. The project has about 10 modules, and it still works fine on my macbook, but when building on ubuntu (tried clean install on 17.10 2 times, and 16.04 2 times as well) will crash the app on start with the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.xxx.xxx.Application: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.xxx.xxx.Application" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.xxx.xxx.debug-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.xxx.xxx.debug-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.xxx.xxx.debug-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:802)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5418)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1558)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.xxx.xxx.Application" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.xxx.xxx.debug-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.xxx.xxx.debug-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.xxx.xxx.debug-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1014)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:796)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5418) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1558) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

I've tried cleaning, rebuilding, invalidating and restarting, 3 different android studio versions (the stable one, 2.3, and latest canary build) on both operating systems (17.10 and 16.04) and I still get exactly same error. Also, I've installed the libraries for 64 bit system. Also, I've tried with oracle java as well.

Does anyone have any clue why a project gets this error on linux but not on mac?

---

**Update**

So I found out that Ubuntu does not see the application class. It has a red label and is not recognized from the manifest file. This is the application class from `app` package and I can only see it if I switch to project view. I'm currently investigating why it doesn't see it.

Comment: are the Platform Images properly installed? the stacktrace shows something related to  `armeabi-v7a`. Can you make sure those system images are installed

Comment: In all use cases, I can start hello world app and everything is fine.  If that answers the question

Comment: looking at the log, I guess the problem is with some of your libraries or your build path they are pointing towards your old path so android is unable to find it. Take a look at these questions maybe they will help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399572/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path-dexpathlist

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866431/android-activity-classnotfoundexception-tried-everything?rq=1

Comment: I thought about that as well. But there are over 7 devs working on this project as well, and everything works good for them.  They are all on osx as well.

Comment: @FilipLuch i am sure the problem is either with some library or the build path. As you can see from the log that it can't find the specific file/class. And if it was with your tool then hello world also wouldn't start either.

Comment: add `multiDexEnabled true`

Comment: I see what you mean @umair but how could I find what caused it?

Comment: can you tell on how many devices/emulators did you tried to run you app ?

Comment: 2 emulators, 3 devices. Various versions

Comment: Like intellij Amiya said have you enabled multiDexEnabled ? and also declared in dependencies and your manifest ?

Comment: Yeah, of course. Multidex has been added correctly. It works fine on Mac, and for all other devs.

Comment: @Umair I just updated the question with more details on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that Ubuntu would not see the Application class, and thus did not consider it on build, as a result it wasn't included in dex files. The thing is that the application class is inside app -> src -> main -> **Java** -> packagename -> Application.class , and Ubuntu did not recognize `Java` as a valid directory. It recognizes it only if it is `java`. So renaming the folder `Java` to `java` has fixed the problem and the application class is now visible.

Morale 1: Always triple check all ridiculous use cases and pay attention to details.

Morale 2: Ubuntu handles folders in a different manner than Mac because Mac couldn't care less if that's capital J or lowercase j.

Comment: 3) Also android always amazes you in ways you don't even think of :P

Comment: Lol this was really hard to catch. Didn't knew Mac is case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing disable Instant Run feature.

you can do it by

```
File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Instant run
```

Click on instant run and then disable the checkbox for Instant Run.

Comment: Yeah, I did that as well and it didn't work. The project doesn't support instant run for now anyway Thank you

Comment: Edited the answer