# Sinch crashes on some Android devices (Launching app)

Tags: android, sinch

The app works fine on some devices but crashes on other devices on start up. Below is the logcat

```
04-13 09:22:20.765 27856-27856/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1336] No 
pending exception expected: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find 
class "com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.natives.HttpRequest" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip 
file "/data/app/com.test-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories= 
[/data/app/com.test-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.test- 
1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
04-13 09:22:20.765 27856-27856/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at 
void com.test.service.SinchService.a(java.lang.String) ((null):-1)
04-13 09:22:20.765 27856-27856/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at 
void com.test.service.SinchService.b(java.lang.String) ((null):-1)
04-13 09:22:20.765 27856-27856/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1336]   at 
void com.test.service.SinchService.onCreate() ((null):-1)
04-13 09:22:31.224 27856-27856/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 
in tid 27856 (com.test)
04-13 09:22:31.334 202-202/? A/DEBUG: pid: 27856, tid: 27856, name: 
com.test>>> com.test<<<
04-13 09:22:31.399 202-202/? A/DEBUG: Abort message:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Instant Run" was the issue. Disabling/Unchecking "Instant Run" fixed the problem.

To disable "Instant Run", Go to **File** -> **Settings** -> **Build,Execution, Deployment** -> **Instant Run** -> **Uncheck the checkbox for "Instant Run"**.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45320244/5437877

**UPDATE: THIS DOES NOT WORK ON app-release.apk files, only app-debug.apk files**

**UPDATE 2: FINALLY FIXED IT**

In build.gradle, make sure minifyEnabled is set to false and don't add

`dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }`

Do it like below:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```