# Failed resolution of: Lorg/jsoup/Jsoup;

Tags: android, jsoup

I created a new module for my project for adding some extra features. In that module, I added Jsoup dependencies in module's Gradle file `implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'` and implement this code to parse a simple HTML code.

```
Document document =  Jsoup.parse(content);
Element element = document.body();
setElement(element);
Utils.appendView(this,getElement().children());
invalidate();
```

On running application, I'm getting this error trace with app crash.

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jsoup/Jsoup;
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.jsoup.Jsoup" on path: DexPathList[[zip
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that you added it to your manifest, then clean your project.

**If you are using Eclipse**, and the problem persists, follow the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22959847/8065149

**If you are using Android Studio**, try disabling instant run: Go to File -> Settings -> Build,Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run -> Uncheck the checkbox for instant run. Run your app once and this apk file shoudld work properly.

And if that small change didn't work, then try something might have went wrong in the incremental build system. One of this should help:

1. Menu Build -> Rebuild project
2. Delete folder /build
3. Close Android Studio, delete /build folder
4. Right click on your project -> "Open module settings" -> Dependencies tab -> check if Export is checked for your library

Comment: Didn't get the `properties` on the right on project.

Comment: I'm not using instant run

Comment: Just disable it anyway, you might be using it without knowing it. Then check my part 2 edit for Android studio

Comment: still throwing the same error. And there is no any option like export in dependencies tab.