# Gradle migration 3.1.4 -> 3.5.1; :app module doesn't compile; ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class on path: DexPathList

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, build

I have two applications where I face the same issue while trying to update project `target` API from 27 to 29. To do this, first I need to update Gradle plugin at least to `3.2.+`.

Project is building fine with `3.1.4`, but as soon as I rise Gradle plugin to:
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1` 
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip`
(Same error with `3.2.1` and higher)

I see next RunTime exception:

```
Process: com.my.app, PID: 29804
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.my.app: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.my.app" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.my.app-Y6_GNyscecqK5BtUnp_kjQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.my.app-Y6_GNyscecqK5BtUnp_kjQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.my.app-Y6_GNyscecqK5BtUnp_kjQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
```

**A problem that *:app* module source code is not compiled at all**
(I can create manual compilation error and *run* will be still successful)

The same in both application. 
What I tired:

- I checked generated DEX files in the APK, source code is not there;
- I create a new project with `3.5.1` plugin - it works fine;
- Tried to delete `gradle` and `.idea` folders;
- Tried to to `clean` and `invalidate cache`
- Migrated project to `AndroidX`;
- Added `multiDexEnabled true` - it was working without it before, anyway;
- Copied dependencies to a new Project - works fine;
- Added: to *gradle.properties* `android.useAndroidX=true android.enableJetifier=true`

My build files:

**TOP level**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:6.0.0"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Application:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.01"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
ext.anko_version='0.10.5'
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.2.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.2.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.1.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk21:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-constraint-layout:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-recyclerview-v7:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-recyclerview-v7-coroutines:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-cardview-v7:$anko_version"
    implementation 'com.r0adkll:slidableactivity:2.0.6'
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.6.1'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.6.1'
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-support-fragment:1.6.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    kapt "io.realm:realm-annotations-processor:5.9.0"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

***Note: another project has different set of dependencies still face the same issue***

Why source code is not added to APK after migration to newer Gradle while working fine on the  old one?

**Update 1** 
Problem appear as soon as I update project to Gradle `3.2+`

**Update 2**
Build folder doesn't contain class folder and class files

**Update 3**
Source code from **:app** module doesn't compile even tho it is in the *settings.gradle* file; I can create build error in any .java file and *run* will be executed *successfully*

Comment: Try the steps mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399572/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path-dexpathlist

Comment: I already tried all possible solutions mentioned in that thread..

Comment: ':app' source code doesn't compile at all, even tho I have it is settings.gradle: include ':app'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an issue:
One of my packages name vas **`cvs`** - seems it is after Gradle 3.2.+ it is reserved word.