# Gradle migration : Unable to instantiate application ClassNotFoundException. Didn't find class “Application” on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dex, android-viewbinding

```
Gradle migration : Unable to instantiate application ClassNotFoundException. Didn't find class “Application” on path: DexPathList
```

The problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58362140/gradle-migration-3-1-4-3-5-1-app-module-doesnt-compile-classnotfoundexcep)

Please **check** it to see what is happening.

I want to find **other reserved words** or **other things** would make this problem.

Comment: did you try enabling multidex. Post your gradle file. a bit more details always help.

Comment: Multidex is enabled, and even https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#multidexkeepfile-property is not working, the problem is with gradle migration @MuhammadUmar

Comment: Can you post your build files?

Comment: The application is modular and use gradle kotlin dsl, I think build files won't help, the documentation of gradle migration from 3.x.x to 4.x.x is not efficient @luca_999.