# Flutter App crash on launching showing some DexPathList error

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

When I start my app its showing this error. I have change my package name but I don't get where this com.epixmobile.dor.DOR is coming I have change every where with com.epixmobile.dor but error is not going.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.epixmobile.dor.DOR: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.epixmobile.dor.DOR" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.epixmobile.dor-L8IEWGPmJboztFwCyW-plQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.epixmobile.dor-L8IEWGPmJboztFwCyW-plQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.epixmobile.dor-L8IEWGPmJboztFwCyW-plQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]
```

Mainactivity.kt

```
package com.epixmobile.dor

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

This is android.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.epixmobile.dor">
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="DOR"
        android:label="DOR"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

               <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" 
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
              <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
        <activity
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"
        />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme Continuas
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that Continuas showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

app/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }
    dependencies {
        // ...
        // OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.10.2, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}
   def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }


def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.epixmobile.dor"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    // compileOptions {
    //     sourceCompatibility 1.8
    //     targetCompatibility 1.8
    // }

   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.2.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:18.0.1'

    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
}
```

I am stuck on this from 3 days and didn't get a single clue how to solve this. There is no answer I have try on whole project I have change package name but don't get from where this com.epixmobile.dor.DOR showing

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399572/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path-dexpathlist

Answer (score 3):

Just remove line `android:name="DOR"` from `<application android:name="DOR" />`
(or define the referenced `Application` class with `class DOR extends Application`).

`AndroidManifest.xml` `application` property [`android:name`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#nm) is being described as:

> The fully qualified name of an [`Application`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application) subclass implemented for the application. When the application process is started, this class is instantiated before any of the application's components.
> **The subclass is optional; most applications won't need one**.
> In the absence of a subclass, Android uses an instance of the base Application class.

Setting `android:name` only works while providing the corresponding `Application` class.