# Unable to instantiate application kotlin runtime error

Tags: firebase, kotlin

I get this error on run time

2023-02-10 10:37:04.008 17261-17261/? E/USNET: USNET: appName: lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment
2023-02-10 10:37:04.251 17261-17261/lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment, PID: 17261
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment.DamroApplication package lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment.DamroApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~jf7fR-0oBIKxMDmk413RUQ==/lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment-82b_ZM-v8B137LudTn0m0Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~jf7fR-0oBIKxMDmk413RUQ==/lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment-82b_ZM-v8B137LudTn0m0Q==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1464)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7458)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:310)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2281)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment.DamroApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~jf7fR-0oBIKxMDmk413RUQ==/lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment-82b_ZM-v8B137LudTn0m0Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~jf7fR-0oBIKxMDmk413RUQ==/lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment-82b_ZM-v8B137LudTn0m0Q==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1177)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1456)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7458) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:310) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2281) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135) 
Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Llk/ac/kln/mit/stu/mobileapplicationdevelopment/Hilt_DamroApplication;
at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment.Hilt_DamroApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~jf7fR-0oBIKxMDmk413RUQ==/lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment-82b_ZM-v8B137LudTn0m0Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~jf7fR-0oBIKxMDmk413RUQ==/lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment-82b_ZM-v8B137LudTn0m0Q==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)

This is my DamroApplication.kt file

```
package lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment

import android.app.Application
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp

@HiltAndroidApp
class DamroApplication : Application() {

}
```

Here is my folder structure

[image: Folder structure]

Below is my AndroidManifest.kt file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:name=".DamroApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MobileApplicationDevelopment"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activitya
            android:name=".activities.ShoppingActivity"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activitya>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LoginRegisterActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild your project? Does one of these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399572/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path-dexpathlist) help?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by following below steps
Device Manager > Edit this AVD > Show Advanced Settings > Emulated Performance > Boot Options > select "Cold Boot"

Then restart Android Studio